# Matching one of list of values, separated by ; in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, match

I have a MySQLi table that has a field that lists indices, and each index is separated by a semi-colon (e.g. '1;5;15'). How can I query which entries list a specific index, bearing in mind that I wouldn't want an entry that lists, for example '15' when I searched for '1'.

Comment: You should normalize your DB. You could replace the semi-colon with a comma then use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set, or you could use some regex.

Comment: Given that you only want complete indexes, you could simply search for <number>; - ie, if you want to find 1, search for 1; - it will only match the exact index.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie In that example, if `51` were also present though that would fail. A regex could work, but is not the best approach, `(^|;)1($|;)`.

Comment: Well, that is true, unless you search for the exact match - but then again, that might be hard to do when you cannot really find an exact match. The real answer is your DB is broken, and should be fixed ;)

Comment: @chris85 is right, without normalizing, it would be ugly. This should do however as your search could be at the beginning, in the middle, at the end or on its own: `WHERE col LIKE '1;%' OR col LIKE '%;1;%' OR col LIKE '%;1' OR col = '1'`

Comment: this is only a problem because of this poor data structure. It should be normalised into separate rows.

Comment: The reason I haven't got it in separate rows, is because there can be one or many indices. The solution I came up with, based on @chris85's answer, was to put ; in front of and after the indices, (e.g. ;1;2;12;), then searching for `LIKE %;1;%`.

Comment: "The reason I haven't got it in separate rows, is because there can be one or many indices.". Then it should be in a separate table, with each row having a foreign key back to the parent row in the main table. And then you can use SQL joins to easily find the results. Look up database normalisation online and read about the key concepts of database design.

Comment: So, would the table have three fields: the primary key, the index of the parent row, and one of the indices I want to reference; and then I'd create an entry for each of the entries?

Comment: yes that's right. And you'd define a foreign key relationship between the parent table and the new table.